# Python: How to get number of rows deleted with MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql-python, delete-row

I have this below code which deletes all the rows in a table whose date column value is current_date.

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost",'root','XXXX','XXXX')
cur = db.cursor()
query = "delete from RealTimeData where date = current_date()"
cur.execute(query)
db.commit()
```

Now, How can I know that How many rows did my query delete from table? 
I tried `fetchone()` it was returning `None`

Comment: and have you tried the function fetchall()?. And you can use the property rowcount from the cursor. "cursor.rowcount"

Comment: Yaa it returns zero sized tuple.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`Cursor.rowcount`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#rowcount) attribute:

```
cur.execute(query)
deleted_row_count = cur.rowcount
```

According to the documentation,

> **`.rowcount`**
>
> This read-only attribute specifies the number of rows that the last
>   .execute*() produced (for DQL statements like SELECT ) or affected
>   (for DML statements like UPDATE or INSERT ). [9]

Answer (score 3):

Using Python 2.7.5, MySQLdb version 1.2.5 in Linux:

The key is that the API returns .rowcount ONLY for SELECT, INSERT, and UPDATE.  From https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/:

> .rowcount:  This read-only attribute specifies the number of rows that the last .execute*() produced (for DQL statements like SELECT ) or affected (for DML statements like UPDATE or INSERT )

Notice there is **NO** mention of this attribute being updated for DELETE.  Closing my old cursor and creating a new one in my application, I saw a result of -1 for .rowcount after a DELETE statement, exactly as documented in PEP249.  (Future note: the return may be changed to None instead of -1.)

So, **Plan B:**

```
with ... as mycursor:
    mycursor.execute("DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id = %s", params=(myindex,))
    mycursor.execute("SELECT ROW_COUNT() as rowcount")
    rows = mycursor.fetchall()
    rowcount = rows[0].get('rowcount', -1)
```

Now, the variable rowcount has the number of rows deleted by the execution of the DELETE SQL command.

Why not use the multi=True parameter?  From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html:

> If multi is set to True, execute() is able to execute multiple statements specified in the operation string. It returns an iterator that enables processing the result of each statement. However, **using parameters does not work well in this case**, and it is usually a good idea to execute each statement on its own.

(Emphasis mine.) Using this code technique, I was able to verify that the DELETE statement actually deleted the record specified.